# VSIX Extension for VS2022: Get the Active Configuration for a CMake Based Project

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2022, vsix

I am currently writing a VSIX extension for Visual Studio 2022. We have a CMake based project  and I want to access the current configuration name of this CMake project from within VSIX. My first try was to access this kind of information along the line of:

```
ServiceProvider s = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider;
DTE dte = (DTE)s.GetService(typeof(DTE));
Projects projs = dte.Solution.Projects;
foreach (Project i in projs)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(i.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration);
}
```

This code fails for our project. Because (and I learned that later) CMake based projects have the  Type `DteMiscProject` which have no `ConfigurationManager` property at runtime.

So how do I access the current active configuration for an open CMake Projekt from within a VSIX project then? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: CMake projects in Visual Studio operate on files, so none of the traditional APIs work for getting information on the solutions/projects. Instead, you simply open .vs/ProjectSettings.json and parse the configuration from there. It updates according to the configuration selected in the VS GUI.

I struggled with this for a while, trying all possible ways found on Google before stumbling on the answer on: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/issues/2508